# Hyperlink Using Query

Tags: php, mysql, database, hyperlink

I have my Search Results being displayed just fine, but I have several categories. I want to be able to select the Column and use ORDER BY. Here's what I have to try and do this.

```
<a href='searchresult.php?db=members&table=people&sql_query=SELECT+%2A+FROM+%60people%60+ORDER+BY+%60lastname%60.%60level%60++DESC+%60AGAINST+$search&token=5e1a18b6cccb5db7a37bb3fce055801a'>Last Name</a>
```

the $search is what I search for. and when I look at the link it shows what I searched for in its place. So I figured this would work, but of course it did not. What would be the right way to set this up for each one of my columns so when I click the link it will sort my results in the order of that column?

Thanks!

Comment: whoa. this is really bad. ***You should NEVER run SQL that is sent from the client.***

Comment: Oh dear... are you actually executing a query that is sent as a URL parameter...?

Comment: NEVER include a query in a link. That is asking for a hacker to defile your database!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input on this. How should I go about sorting my results by selecting a column category? I have several different columns. I do have a ORDER BY setup in my query, but I also want the option of clicking each column to order after the results are shown.

Comment: Well whoever gave me the -1 Sorry to inconvenience your day by looking at an issue that someone was having. and instead of correcting the mistake you just - the post... Again thanks to the people who helped point out what I was doing wrong. I really appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that should SCREAM at you is to **NEVER** run any SQL query that contains any input that could possibly come from a client without first sanitizing it. Running an entire query from (potentially) user input will allow them to run a command like `DROP DATABASE` or `TRUNCATE TABLE`, or worse, they could get sensitive information out of it.

So you should hard-code your SQL query and just take the user input for the specific values you are querying for, but first sanitize those, by doing something like this:

`$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM 'people' ORDER BY %s DESC", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["orderby"]));`

Now, on to your actual question...after the page has been loaded, you have two options:

1. You could re-query using AJAX.
2. You could sort the table using Javascript.

Which is better really depends on how many rows you are expecting.

If you are fetching a lot of rows, sorting via Javascript starts getting pretty slow, but if it's just a few rows (like less than 100 or so), then Javascript is probably the way to go. I don't know much about other libraries, like JQuery or otherwise, not sure if they have a better solution. So for a lot of rows, using AJAX to just re-query the database is probably faster.

However, if your page consists of just this table by itself, there's not really any point in using AJAX as opposed to just refreshing the page with a different query.

If you do decide to sort the table using Javascript, [a library like this one](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/) might help. Or just google "javascript sort table".

Comment: Thank You Travesty3, the JavaScript is what I needed. I was over thinking and thought it would be more difficult then that. it works great!